# what is the meaning of [3] in int(*p)[3]?

Tags: arrays, pointers

I'm studying array and pointer in c++.
In this code, I can't understand the meaning of [3] in 'int (*c)[3] = a'.
Is is came from 'int a[2][3]'??
But there is two numbers, 2 and 3.
Why don't we use [2]?
Please let me know the rule of number next to (*c).

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int a[2][3] = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}};

        cout << "\n";

        int (*c)[3] = a; // type of a and c: int (*)[3]
        cout << "c + 1 = " << c + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Distance between c + 1 and a: " <<
            reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(c+1) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a) 
        << "\n";


        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**a** is a two-dimensional array, 2 sets of 3 integers.

**c** is a pointer to a single-dimensional array of 3 integers.
In **c**'s declaration the [3] defines the size of **c**.

Since **c** is a pointer, setting **c** = **a** points **c** to the first triple in **a** (c[0]=>a[0][0], c[1]=>a[0][1], c[2]=>a[0][2])

That [3] on **c** becomes important when we increment: **c + 1** is actually **a[1]**, the second triple in **a**. The pointer **c** gets increased by the size of **c**, which is int[3].

Clear as mud?  :-)